# How do I view a new window C# Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

im trying to change window when the "EASY" (easyBtn) is being pressed, I basically want the current window to change into a new one with a few other buttons, but I really have no clue on what the code should look like, im used to the .NET framework. (Im new to Android Developing)

--QUESTION-- 
So how do I view a new window when the "EASY" button is being pressed?

Here is my current code (As you will see I got kinda stuck.

```
namespace The_Coder_Quiz
{
    [Activity(Label = "The_Quiz", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);



            //EasyBtn

            Button easyBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.easyBtn);
            easyBtn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {


                //this button will generate a new empty window when being pressed




            };
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding a RelativeLayout and connecting the button to it so it changes on keypress but I couldnt find any code examples to learn from.
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to start another activity.

You need to create a new Activity (right click your Project, select "Add Item" and click Activity) Then

```
button.Click += delegate {
   StartActivity(typeof(Activity2));
};
```

See
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/

Comment: I will try that out! Thank you!

Comment: It worked, thanks! But how do I get the Design window to change so I can add new buttons to the new activity?
Like this one
https://i.gyazo.com/92826eaf9a0857095dd54b84d2fc09ba.png

Comment: @VargaDev Create a new Layout, and in your Activity2's OnCreate, call SetContentView to set the layout of Activity2 to be the new layout you made

Comment: I just figured that out, was about to come back and say that but you beat me to it! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new xml (and that is the design of the new window you will go to) and also new class and extends its code to AppComppact and ovrride onCreate method by ctrl+o and set its contentView the new xml like that :

```
package example.gsdfgsdf.gadfgsfgs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YourNewXML);
    }
```

and also declare the that Activity (xml and class) in the manifest.xml like that

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <activity
            android:name=".YourDesiredActivityApperedNameInApp"
            android:label="YourNewXMLAppearedNameInTheNavBar"/>
    </activity>
```

and set the button on click in the main xml like that

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn7_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="YourNewOnClickMethode"
    android:text="7"/>
```

and create the onClick in the main Activity (you are on now) like that

```
public void YourNewOnClickMethode(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How is that different to the method above? This seem like a longer way to get there.

Comment: it works the same just you do not have only one way to reach your goal, I did not know of the above method I just saw it now, and the way i explain it to you I learned from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: and by creating a new Activity you are already defining the new xml and class in the manifest also seting its ContentView just didnot set the onClick of the button and the last step the Intent just i explained it more not let you create the activity without knowing how it is created

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! WIll keep that in mind!